# How do I export a GWT project into a executable JAR file with Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

There's a huge legacy codebase that I'm working with and I need to export it into an executable JAR file to make it easier for my co-workers to run it. It's a web application built on top of GWT, but I'm not sure what kind of application server it uses (e.g. Apache Tomcat, Eclipse tells me it uses a "built-in" server).

The run configuration shows up when I try to run the project, but not when I'm trying to export it as an executable JAR. All it does is run an application server on the machine, and allows a user to access it via 127.0.0.1:8888 in a web browser. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the project.
Google
GWT Compile

Zip the output (I think the war folder) into a war file which can be deployed in tomcat or jetty or something else.

(Creating an executable jar from a GWT project is not possible, you should create a war).

(Make sure to have the eclipse google plugin installed (https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/getting_started))

Comment: Thanks, all your steps work perfectly! I want to package Tomcat with the WAR file and make the web app auto-open itself in a browser though, so the web application feels like a one-click executable. Could you expand to include this?

Comment: Package `TOMCAT` along with the war?